# New Job Offer After Accepting A Temporary Reseach Position (New Grad)

Tags: email-etiquette

I will graduate this May from my degree program and was recently offered a full-time role that would start in end of June. However, about a month ago I accepted a Spring & Summer 2021 research position a month ago which supposedly would last till August. Though I assumed the position to be unpaid, the professor with whom I work told me earlier that she would be able to offer a small compensation over the summer and the exact amount would depend on the number of hours and weeks I can commit to.

I am not sure what would be the appropriate way to inform her that I have obtained and accepted a full-time offer that would start earlier than she would like to. I appreciate your help in this matter!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reneging offer for a much better one](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/169342/reneging-offer-for-a-much-better-one)

Answer (score 1):

if the professor is able to stop you graduate, or have any impact to your graduate or something else, then talk with her first, be fully honestly.

If he is a reasonable person, then I believe he would support you. But if not, you'd better not say anything. Because now you graduate successfully is the top priority. Because you never lose chance, you are young!

If the professor is NOT able to impact you, then do what you want, just tell her the truth. Be earlier be better, instead of last minute.

Answer (score -1):

Apart from trying to get you in trouble and under extreme pressure, for performing two works at the same time, I see no reason for NOT telling the professor exactly what you wrote here.

State that you can commit only until the end of June, so she knows that she has fundings available (the one allocated for you that will not be used by you) to be allocated to another student.

Comment: @YumekaMengjiaLYU I realized I missed a NOT in my answer Whoops, sorry!